# The async-await syntax is not working synchronously as I expected in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestProcess();
        }
    
        private async void TestProcess()
        {
            proc_TestAll();
    
            Task tsk_TestEnd = new Task(proc_TestEnd);
            tsk_TestEnd.Start();
            await tsk_TestEnd;
        }
        private async void proc_TestAll()
        {
            Task task1 = new(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); });
            task1.Start();
            await task1;
    
            while(true)
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("proc_TestAll Fin");
        }
        private void proc_TestEnd()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("proc_TestEnd Fin");
        }
```

I expect that pressing the button will finish task1 in proc_TestAll, then output it to the console (after 3 seconds of sleep), and then run the task running proc_TestEnd. However, the result is that TestEnd Task will run immediately before Sleep is finished. What is the problem?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: You're not awaiting the call to `proc_TestAll` so the code is going to continue on.  FYI you can use `await Task.Delay(3000);` instead and you don't need to create new Tasks, just do `var task = proc_TestEnd();` to get the Task.  Also you really should have async all the way to the top and make `button1_Click` `async void`, but the other methods should be `async Task`.

Comment: [Avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) and [never use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary Ironically they didn't use `async void` in the one place they should have.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Attempts to asynchronously execute multiple methods within proc_TestAll and wait for them to all complete. How can I run all of them asynchronously without using the Task constructor for each method?

Comment: @user [`Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)?

Comment: @Llama How do I wait for all to complete after executing, for example, five methods with Task.Run()? await Task.Run (Action)-This prevents each method from running synchronously?
How can I run everyone asynchronously and wait without writing a constructor?

Comment: @user15588017: If you need to run synchronous code on a background thread, then use `Task.Run`. If the methods are asynchronous, then you can invoke them all but don't `await` right away and then use `await Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: `Task.Run` isn't blocking.

Comment: @StephenCleary Did you say it's good to make a work like this? - Task[] tmpTask =
{
Task.Run(proc1),
Task.Run(proc2),
Task.Run(proc3),
Task.Run(proc4),
Task.Run(proc5),
Task.Run(proc6)
};

await Task.WhenAll(tmpTask);
Each proc is void type method.

Comment: Thanks for all of answers, I got to solve with your solutions. Good day :)

Comment: @user15588017: If the code is synchronous, then yes, that is an acceptable solution.

Comment: In general two options are: I/O-bound (async) `await Task.Delay(3000);` and CPU-bound (sync in thread) `await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(3000));` make two changes to fix the behavior `private async Task proc_TestAll()` and `await proc_TestAll();`